# How would I make data disappear when successfully submitted

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I want user inserted data to disappear from the input field when it is submitted successfully and it should be in the field if it fails to submit e.g. such as duplicate of data.

I have a form that will accept user input and submit it to the database and I use JavaScript to communicate with my form and PHP Script, so now I want when data is successfully submitted it should disappear and when it fails it should be there.

This is the HTML code

```
<form role="form">
        <div class="box-body">

        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputClass">Class Title</label>
    <input type="class" class="form-control" id="inputClass" placeholder="Class Title">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="selectSection">Class Section</label>
    <select name="selectSection" id="selectSection" class="form-control" required="required">
    <option selected disabled>Class Section</option>
    <?php echo(getSection()); ?>
    </select>
    </div>

    <span id="loading"><img src="../assets/images/loading.gif" height="40px" width="100%" alt="Ajax Indicator" /></span>
    </div>
    <!-- /.box-body -->

    <div class="box-footer">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="registerClass">Submit</button>
    </div>
    </form>
```

And the JavaScript code is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#loading').hide();
        $('#registerClass').click(function(){
    $('#loading').show();
        $.post("check-class.php", {
            inputClass: $('#inputClass').val(),  
            selectSection: $('#selectSection').val()          
        }, function(response){
            $('#resultInfo').fadeOut();
            setTimeout("finishAjax('resultInfo', '"+escape(response)+"')", 2000);
        });
        return false;
    });
});

function finishAjax(id, response) {
    $('#loading').hide();
    $('#'+id).html(unescape(response));
    $('#'+id).fadeIn();
}
</script>
```

I expected to disappear when successfully but unfortunately it is still there

Answer (score 1):

Add id attribute in form tag and use that id to reset form data in finishAjax function like:

```
document.getElementById(' ID THAT MENTIONED IN FORM TAG ').reset();
```

Comment: where would I add the script, please?

Answer (score 0):

You should reset the from by adding an Id to from like

```
 <form role="form" id ="myFrom">
```

and then reset from, once you received response from server and want to clear the form values

```
document.getElementById('myFrom').reset();
```

You can add this reset logic in finishAjax function

```
  function finishAjax(id, response) {
            $('#loading').hide();
            $('#'+id).html(unescape(response));
            $('#'+id).fadeIn();
            document.getElementById('myFrom').reset();
        }
```